# Bash - getting the current user CPU utilisation

Tags: bash

I'm trying to do what I think is quite a simple task, yet I am hitting an odd problem, and unfortunately with my limited Bash experience (I generally use Ruby for scripts) I need some help.

All I am trying to do is write a script that simple checks CPU utilisation, and if utilisation is over a particular amount, it will do something.

So I started off by simply capturing CPU utilisation from `top` as follows:

```
 CPU_SUMMARY=(`top -b -n 1 | grep ^Cpu`)
```

Unfortunately, when I check what comes out of this, I get some extra information at the start:

```
$ echo $CPU_SUMMARY
24ms, 0.8y, 0.0ubuntui, 97.77d, 0.2Tue 9a, 0.0137i, 0.0i, 0.2tCpu(s): 1.1%us, 0.8%sy, 0.0%ni, 97.7%id, 0.2%wa, 0.0%hi, 0.0%si, 0.2%st
```

Where is the "24ms, 0.8y...0.2t" coming from?  If I run the same command `top -b- n 1 | grep ^Cpu` without trying to assign it to variable, I get:

```
Cpu(s):  1.1%us,  0.8%sy,  0.0%ni, 97.7%id,  0.2%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.2%st
```

So I am just a bit confused as to why that initial 24ms... text is coming from.

I even tried extracting the bit I wanted out, ignoring the additional text as follows:

```
$ echo $CPU_SUMMARY | grep -o -E "[0-9\.]+%us"
24ms, 0.8y, 0.0ubuntui, 97.77d, 0.2Tue 9a, 0.0142i, 0.0i, 0.2t | grep -o -E "[0-9\.]+s"1.1%us
```

And I get the same thing?

I am un Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks for your help.

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to improve your example use following egrep

```
$ echo $CPU_SUMMARY | egrep -o '([0-9\.]+%us)'
1.1%us
```

On the other hand this will sum all CPU usage (in 3rd column of ps output from example)

```
$ ps fuxw | awk '{ if ($3 ~ /^[0-9]/) {SUM +=$3}} END  {print SUM"%"}'      
18.5%
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I run that command, I still get the following: `$ echo $CPU_SUMMARY | egrep -o '([0-9\.]+%us)'` returns `24ms, 0.8y, 0.0ubuntui, 97.77d, 0.2Tue 9a, 0.0143i, 0.0i, 0.2t | egrep -o '([0-9\.]+s)'1.1%us`

Comment: BTW. For your latter example, that seems to work quite well, however it appears to only be adding up the root processes? Surely one would need it to use all processes for the calculation?

Comment: if you want all processes just add 'a' as in 'ps fuxwa' to ps command... egrep works on my system as shown in example; check which shell are you running

Comment: Using `zsh`, any reason why that would be a problem?

Comment: BTW. With your latter example, the `ps fuxw` version, I deliberately set a process to 100% and ran the command, and the CPU utilisation for that process was low.  It seems to be using an average instead of actual.  Any idea how that can use actual instead?

Comment: BTW. I used this command instead to get actual CPU utilisation, and it seems to work well, `top -b -n 1 | awk '{ if ($9 ~ /^[0-9]/) {SUM +=$9}} END  {print SUM"%"}'`